# Remove while space after scaling

Tags: css

In the below code I have too much white space in between `divright` and `divright2`. How can I fix this problem?

```
<div id="leftdiv"></div>
<div id="rightdiv"></div>
<div id="rightdiv2">This should start quick under rightdiv</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#leftdiv{
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#rightdiv{
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}
#rightdiv2{
    clear:right;
     float:right;   
}
}
```

Output can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/4Msr6/

Comment: You are scaling the element, but the width and height stay the same, so you need to push the `#rightdiv2` with negative margin.

Comment: How about using margins and paddings?

Comment: @drip - May work, will try it. thanks

Comment: @drip - Doesn't seems good idea. :( Can't figure out proper dimensions, I am worried it may effect in other browsers.

Comment: @lock Is this the one you look for http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/4Msr6/3/

Comment: @JudeArasu - Looking for `rightdiv2` perfectly aligned under `rightdiv` only. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

i know its late. but i am replying so that this will help to someone who is having the same issue

```
#leftdiv{
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#rightdiv{
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    **margin-bottom: -90px;**
}
#rightdiv2{
    clear:right;
     float:right;   
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Msr6/10/